# How to mimic/implement a WYSWYG editor on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor

All I know is that it uses a `IFRAME` tag as it's presentation layer, how does it store the data, how does it switch between **WYSIWYG** mode and source mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most in-browser **WYSIWYG** editors (Google Docs is a notable exception) use the [contenteditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) attribute to make an element editable.

The data doesn't need to be stored in any special way, it's just the HTML content of the editable node.

Switch to source mode by dumping the `innerHTML` of your editable element into a `textarea`, showing the `textarea`, and hiding the editable element.

You can find lots of information and tutorials by googling `contenteditable`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use one of the many free ones:

http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/

example: http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/help/examples/03-ajax.html